# How to query an array of integers ​in an integer collection in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I would like to query an integer collection. For now, I can only filter by the first value in the array of integers. How can I query that includes all values ​​in the integer array for a blog tag id collection?

```
 //list --> my blog posts variable

 ....
 if (f.blogTagIds != null)
 {
     list = list.Where(p => p.BlogTagRelation.Select(p => p.BlogTagId).Contains(f.blogTagIds[0]));
 }
 ....
```

SearchFilterClass

```
public class SearchFilterType
{
    ...  
    public int[] blogTagIds { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

ViewBag BlogTags

```
var BlogTags = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var item in _uow.BlogTag.GetAllByEnabledDate(null, _uow.Cookie.GetAdminLangId, _uow.Cookie.GetAdminWebSiteId))
{
    BlogTags.Add(new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Text = item.Title,
                         Value = item.Id.ToString()
                     });
}

ViewBag.BlogTags = BlogTags;
```

Filter Form BlogTagIds Select Control

```
<select asp-for="f.blogTagIds" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" asp-items="ViewBag.BlogTags"></select>
```

BlogTagRelation.cs

```
    public partial class BlogTagRelation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public int BlogTagId { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public virtual BlogTag BlogTag { get; set; }
}
```

Example route

```
/Blog/list?f.blogTagIds=8&f.blogTagIds=6
```

Comment: Can you share BlogTagRelation.cs?

Comment: Sorry for this. I will edit my question. I updated

Comment: Linq-to-sql is not Entity Framework (which you probably use). Please pay attention to tag descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var list =list.Where(x => blogTagIds.All(r => x.BlogTagRelation.Any(y => y.BlogTag.BlogTagId== r)));
```

make sure that All of the blogTagIds are contained in BlogTagRelation

result:

[I select user with special roleId]

[image]